# Generating many trajectories and trajectory filter without ShortCutter

Tags: ros, jointtrajectory, trajectory-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am trying to generate diverse set of trajectories for doing a given task (e.g. moving an object from A to B). Currently I am generating such a set of trajectories by changing goal bias of RRT algorithm. All the trajectories obtained using this method have different number of points and hence they should be different. But after passing them through trajectory_filter all the trajectories becomes same and with same number of points.

From what I understand trajectory filter (`CubicSplineShortCutterFilterJointTrajectoryWithConstraints`) tries to both smoothen and shorten the trajectories. Is it possible to just obtain a smoothen trajectory without any shortening? I can't by-pass trajectory_filter because I also need the time and velocity information.

Moreover, I am not able to get the difference between trajectory_filter and joint_trajectory_generator. It appears to me that both servers almost the same purpose. But I guess joint_trajectory_generator onny smoothens the trajectory and doesn't do any kind of trajectory shortening.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Thanks!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57226/generating-many-trajectories-and-trajectory-filter-without-shortcutter/) by [Ashesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4149/ashesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two packages containing a bunch of trajectory filters that you could use: `spline_smoother` and `constraint_aware_spline_smoother`. If you look in `spline_smoother/default_plugins.xml`, you can find a list of plugins that will just fill in timing information without doing any short-cutting. I don't recall the full details of each filter (there are many), but for a start you could try replacing your filter with this one: `spline_smoother/CubicSplineVelocityScalerFilterJointTrajectoryWithConstraints`.

---

Originally posted by [kalakris](https://answers.ros.org/users/17/kalakris/) with karma: 529 on 2013-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0